# Multivariate proof using chain rule I think

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I think I have to use the chain rule... but I am pretty lost... here is the question:

> If $$u =f(x), \quad v =g(y),\quad x = \phi(r,s),\quad y = \psi(r,s),$$
>   prove that $$\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(r,s)}=f'g'\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,s)}$$
>   if 
>   $$\frac{\partial(f,g)}{\partial(p,q)}= \det\begin{pmatrix}
> f_p & f_q \\
> g_p & g_q \\
> \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: yea... working on math on a friday night..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you'll have to use the chain rule.

Hint: it might be clearer if you wrote out the determinants. I.e., as:

$$u_r v_s - u_s v_r = f'g'(x_r y_s - x_s y_r)$$

And what's $u_r$, for example? $u_r = \partial u/\partial r = \partial/\partial r(f(x)) = f' \partial x/\partial r = f'x_r$.

Comment: thanks, i'm still thinking about it. The chain rule was so easy in calc 3...

Comment: @Neo see my edit.

Comment: I think i got it... i wish i could give you guys both answer creds

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by placing the equations in matrix.
$$
\frac{\partial(u, v)}{\partial(r, s)} = \det \begin{pmatrix}
u_r & u_s \\
v_p & v_s \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, using given functions for $u$ and $v$;

$$
\begin{align}
u_r &= \frac{\partial f(\phi(r, s))}{\partial r} \\
&= f' \cdot \frac{\partial \phi(r, s)}{\partial r}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, find $u_s$, $v_r$ and $v_s$. Put them in the first matrix/determinant form.

Comment: i see, ill keep at it thanks guys! I wish i could give u both answer creds